# Ending a for loop, Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm writing a program that reads an integer number "n" from the user, and then add the numbers `1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+...±n^2` together. For example if n = 7, then the program will return 28. I've done it like this:

```
n = int(input("n = "))
summ = 0

for number in range (1,n +1):
    square = (number**2)*((-1)**(number+1))
    summ += square
    print(square)

print("The loop ran",number,"times, the sum is", summ)
```

The problem is that I want the program to end *before* the sum reaches an input "k" from the user.

```
n = int(input("n = "))
k = int(input("k = "))

summ = 0

for number in range (1,n +1):
    square = (number**2)*((-1)**(number+1))
    summ += square
    print(square)
    if summ > k:
        break


print("The loop ran",number,"times, the sum is", summ)
```

If k = 6, the program returns "The loop ran 5 times, the sum is 15", but 15 is obviously over 6. The correct answer would be "The loop ran 4 times, the sum is -10". Does anyone know how to fix this? I've also tried putting the if statement right under the "for number" line, but that returns "The loop ran 6 times, the sum is 15".

Comment: test `summ + square` instead, before adding to `summ`

Comment: Have a separate variable which you check before updating `summ`.

Comment: you could just subtract off the values when you print (if this is all you're doing) `print("The loop ran",number-1,"times, the sum is", summ-square)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the `summ` value and then checking the condition. You should instead check the total before actually adding the number to the sum.

```
for number in range(1, n+1):
    square = (number**2)*((-1)**(number+1))
    if summ + square > k:
        break
    summ += square
    ...

# this should work, assuming the rest of your code works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a condition before adding the square to summ

```
if summ + square > 7:
    break
```

```
n = int(input("n = "))
summ = 0

for number in range (1,n +1):
    square = (number**2)*((-1)**(number+1))
    if summ + square > 7:
        break
    summ += square

    print(square)

print("The loop ran",number,"times, the sum is", summ)
```